# Black screen problem in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, display, screen, 22.04, display-manager

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Dell laptop with [intel core i3 processor, amd-64 architecture, inbuilt graphics]. Recently I have updated my laptop to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04.

After installing, it works fine and runs smoothly, but after some time it shows black screen for about 5 seconds in the cycle of 10 minutes.

What is happening here? There is no problem with my laptop because it works fine with other distros and I have tested it on about 20 different types of distros.

Is there a solution to it?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue on Intel NUC, Core i3 7100U after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04. The behavior looks like a power saving action, where screen goes blank and remains blank until a mouse movement. I still haven't figured out steps to reproduce this. It happens at random. More on this * I tried disabled screen blank option in power settings * Issue happens on both Wayland and X11 * I noticed the same issue in virtualbox while testing Ubuntu 22.04. The host at that time was Ubuntu 20.04.4. * I've upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on another machine, Dell Vostro 3405 with AMD Ryzen 5 3450U. This i

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Was fine in 20.04. Started after upgrade to 22.04 Everything is upgraded, nothing seems broken. But there are other issues which I don't know if they are related. add-apt-repository doesn't work - times out. reinstalling everything relevant hasn't helped. System was working perfectly in 20.04.

Comment: same issue on a NUC7i5 after recent upgrade to 22.04. Any luck?
Will follow this thread for updates!

Comment: This may be related to a mismatch b/w the sender and receiver disagreeing in the bits-per-color transmitted.  This will hopefully be fixed with https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/2412, also cf. the linked Ubuntu launchpad bug.

Comment: I am experiencing issues with 22.04 on Dell Latitude 5500. Every now and then, the wifi powers down for no reason; and just today, out of the sudden, the system disconnected everything at once - wifi, bluetooh, the mouse on an USB dongle, a keyboard on an USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing a similar issue once I migrated from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.  In my case it turned out to be a Dell ‎D3100 docking station that was causing it.  I replaced the docking station with a different one, same model, and the problem went away.

Are you using a docking station when you're seeing this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not using docking station. First I thought that this problem is due to this version of Ubuntu 22.04.  So I upgraded my laptop to newer Ubuntu 22.10 and the problem is gone.