# black screen when no window open 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, nemo

I just upgraded to 22.04 and have a strange error. Ubuntu behaves completely normally, provided *at least one* window is open. This could be a folder, application like Firefox, whatever, as long as it's something. If all windows are closed, the desktop background goes completely black and the launcher and panel disappear, but the icons still display. Eventually, this will flicker back to the expected desktop. Any ideas what's going on here or how to troubleshoot?

The closest thing I can find is [Black screen problem in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406369/black-screen-problem-in-ubuntu-22-04), but this isn't the issue.

Update: After some trouble shooting, I've discovered the behavior is being caused by nemo-desktop. Any ideas?